# May I know if we can import an excel with a particular formatting (my case it is coloured as yellow) using SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis-2012

May I know if we can import an excel with a particular formatting (my case it is coloured as yellow) using SSIS. Now, I have to manually remove the unwanted columns and post in a drive from where the SSIS picks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is for *programming* work, and is not a tech support forum for SSIS or other tools.